# i corrupted my internal harddrive on my phone. (the drive where the /image folder is)

Tags: boot-loop, huawei

well. a few weeks ago, i was flashing roms to my new huawei mercury m886. i am an android developer, and i did the stupidest thing i could ever do. i needed to get into a paranoid android rom, and it was for galaxy s3. unzipping it was taking to long, so i decided to flash it to my phone. well, when i went into download mode, i could get to the files, but whenever i tried to delete something, windows file manager kept telling me, cant delete. disk is write protected. so, i took the battery out of my phone, restarted it, and it just stayed stuck in a bootloop. (the huawei logo). what do i do. i just found out last week that my drive is corrupted. please help. thankyou. Daniel

Comment: As you describe a boot-loop, check the first-aid hints in our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) first. As a last resort, a factory-reset via recovery menu ("wipe data/cache") should solve your issue, though you might need to re-flash a working ROM.

Comment: when i try to wipe data and cache, i get an error. i have also tried flashing new custom roms, stock roms, and a rom in the form of a nandroid backup. in windows 8, when i connect my phone in backup mode and try to delete the /image folder, it deletes it, but when i try to format the drive, windows says unable to complete format. disk is write protected.

Comment: Wait: are we talking about the SDCard, or about internal storage? You cannot just format internal storage from Windows! First, Windows doesn't even understand the file system format used there (ExtFS), and second, even if it would, the device would never permit low-level access there. Could you please [edit] your question, and give a few more details on what exactly you are doing, including the exact error messages your are receiving?

Comment: by backup mode i meant download mode. sorry. when i hook it up to my windows 8 hp pavillion while on the pink screen, i get a wINDOIWS POPUP WITH a folder called /image. inside the files contained are backup.image, paranoidandroid4.3.zip, and a few other files. when i rooted my phone a whileback, i replaced the backup image  in there with a new cwm backup image. that is how i know that you can edit the files in ther. -->

Comment: Sure, but that's one thing. You wrote *but when i try to format the drive, windows says unable to complete format*. What is it you are trying to format there? I doubt it's your SDcard in UMS mode.

Comment: the errors i get when i try to clear the /cache folder in cwm (and this is in the logs), 
formating cache
error formating cache!
I:skipping execution of of extendcommand, file not found...
formating /cache
I:formating unknown device
I:formating ext3 device
tune2fs 1.41.6 (30-MAY-2009)
setting current mount count to 1
e2fsck 1.41.6 (30-may-2009)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6: error recovering journal
/sbin/e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on dev/block/mmcblk0p

failure while running e2fsck
failure while running e2fsck
error formating /cache!

Comment: im trying to format the internal drive where the /image folder is. by reading articles, i saw you could fix it like that, or am i totaly wrong.

Comment: baSaically., i accidentaly flashed a paranoidandroid rom for a galaxy device to my huawei mercury. now, whenever i try to boot, i stay stuck at the huawei logo. when i try to flash a new rom after formating and clearing dalvik cache, i still get stuck a the huawei logo. i tried a rom called the avengerrom. you flash it as a nandroid backup. i tried that and when i boot up i still get stuck at the huawei logo. this all hapened about 4 weeks ago to now. i can boot in to cwm, i can get to the pink screen, and i a not getting the blue screen of death.

Comment: i just got a new rom and put it onto my sd card. what do i do next